# Django AttributeError: 'getfullargspec' object has no attribute 'default'

Tags: python, django

I teared down Django-oscar for practice and rebuild it not in capacity of a plugin app but as Django project. Now I am having this issue but couldn't figure out what it is related to exactly. Can someone help me to resolve this?
Following is the error I am getting:

When I run command "`python manage.py shell`" I get this error.

```
(supermarket) C:\Users\shazia\supermarket\market>python manage.py shell
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\shazia\supermarket\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\_
_init__.py", line 354, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\shazia\supermarket\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\_
_init__.py", line 346, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\shazia\supermarket\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\b
ase.py", line 394, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\shazia\supermarket\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\b
ase.py", line 445, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\shazia\supermarket\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\c
ommands\shell.py", line 69, in handle
    self.run_shell(shell=options['interface'])
  File "C:\Users\shazia\supermarket\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\c
ommands\shell.py", line 58, in run_shell
    return getattr(self, shell)()
  File "C:\Users\shazia\supermarket\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\c
ommands\shell.py", line 41, in ipython
    ip()
  File "C:\Users\shazia\supermarket\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\c
ommands\shell.py", line 34, in _ipython
    from IPython import start_ipython
  File "C:\Users\shazia\supermarket\lib\site-packages\IPython\__init__.py", li
ne 47, in <module>
    from .core.application import Application
  File "C:\Users\shazia\supermarket\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\application
.py", line 22, in <module>
    from traitlets.config.application import Application, catch_config_error
  File "C:\Users\shazia\supermarket\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\__init_
_.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .application import *
  File "C:\Users\shazia\supermarket\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\applica
tion.py", line 120, in <module>
    class Application(SingletonConfigurable):
  File "C:\Users\shazia\supermarket\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\applica
tion.py", line 291, in Application
    def initialize(self, argv=None):
  File "<decorator-gen-1>", line 2, in catch_config_error
  File "C:\Users\shazia\supermarket\lib\site-packages\decorator.py", line 232,
 in decorate
    evaldict, __wrapped__=func)
  File "C:\Users\shazia\supermarket\lib\site-packages\decorator.py", line 219,
 in create
    self = cls(func, name, signature, defaults, doc, module)
  File "C:\Users\shazia\supermarket\lib\site-packages\decorator.py", line 109,
 in __init__
    setattr(self, a, getattr(argspec, a))
AttributeError: 'getfullargspec' object has no attribute 'default'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on Windows as per the error description. Use 'manage.py shell' instead of 'python manage.py shell'.